# Is it possible to dispute the closure of a question?

Tags: discussion, support

I have seen, a couple of times now, a well-written question describing a real Magento problem that needs a real solution, and it's been closed as off-topic. In both cases I strongly disagree that the question *is* off-topic.

Example: [Random Installation Wizard Redirect Magento 1.9.0.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30110/random-installation-wizard-redirect-magento-1-9-0-1)

The reason given was that the problem "can't be reproduced OR seemingly went away on its own (or went away when a typo was fixed)". In the above case, none of these things are true. The problem turned out to be difficult to reproduce, not impossible, and didn't go away on its own.

The question was closed the same day it was asked. Talk about an itchy trigger finger! Did the people involved in closing it actually bother to check if it really met the criteria?

Sorry, I didn't intend for this question to be an appeal about another question. My point is, what *can* I do to appeal cases such as this? Do I have to be the person who originally asked it?

- I could try editing the question, like it suggests in the closure notice, but I see someone already tried that to no avail.
- At the moment I can't add comments as I only have 33 rep.
- I tried clicking through to the profile of one of the people who closed it, and his profile page explicitly states he won't read StackExchange emails since no-one's paying him to do so. Should I, as he goes on to suggest, ask the same question again? What's to stop him closing that one?

Comment: Reopened, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting here works. We'll figure out a good cadence and age for closures.